# Computational Complexity of $\log(\log^{*}(n)) = \Omega(\log^{*}(\log (n)))$

Tags: computational-complexity

would you please explain me why does below equation hold?
$$\log(\log^{*}(n)) = \Omega(\log^{*}(\log (n)))$$

This means that $\log^{*}(\log (n))$ in big $n$'s has a lower growth compared to $\log(\log^{*}(n))$

On the other hand, I have read in the book that $\text{logarithmic functions}$ have the same growth(theta of each other)

Comment: What is logarithm with asterisk?

Comment: @zkutch that is an university question that asked us. btw , it means that it can be repeated 0 to infinite

Comment: Ok. Then if it is only composition of logarithms what is difference between $\log^{*}(\log n)$ and $\log(\log^{*} n)$ ?

Comment: @zkutch that's why i am asking for :)

Comment: From you definition - nothing, if under $*$ you understand same amount of compositions in one and second case. But as here maybe something more subtle, can you share your book, source from which you took definition?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797617/what-does-log-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1 this definition make more sense, are you agree with it?

Comment: @zkutch sounds good materials there i have to read there and see if it gives answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose we take definition of $\log^{*}$ from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3797617/what-does-log-mean?noredirect=1&lq=1) where definition says "The iterated logarithm is the number of times the logarithm has to be applied before the result becomes one or less".

So if we start from $n$ and apply $\log^{*}$, suppose, this gives $k$ steps of logarithm compositions until it becomes one or less. If for same $n$ we consider as start point $\log n$, then obviously we will have $k-1$ steps of logarithms composition from $\log^{*}$. Formally, for sufficiently big $n$, we have
$$\log^{*}(\log n)=\log^{*}(n)-1 > \log(\log^{*}(n))$$

Comment: can you please edit my post and put it mathematical styles ?

Comment: Done. Tell me, please, if something is not that did you plan.

Comment: your answer is correct and i did tried it but i think instead of big-omega it must be Big-O

Comment: May be. Let me some time to think and search for this term and I return back. Meanwhile if/when you find some book with exact definition, please, post it here.

Comment: that was an university question and i have not seen any about iterative log on that but what i know is log k = O(k)

Comment: and your equation shows correct k-1> log k